# How make datepicker filed in bootstrap-vue clear after choosing a date in vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using bootsrap-vue.
It has a datepicker which after picking a date there is no way to make field clear.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="datepicker-placeholder">Date picker with placeholder</label>
    <b-form-datepicker id="datepicker-placeholder" placeholder="Choose a date" locale="en"></b-form-datepicker>
  </div>
</template>
```

How can I clear the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

Either bind a property to 's v-model, and then use JavaScript to reset the value of said property.

The other option is to use the `reset-button` prop, which adds a reset button to the datepicker popup which clears the selected date when clicked by default.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      date: ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <b-input-group>
    <b-datepicker v-model="date" reset-button></b-datepicker>
    <template #prepend>
      <b-btn @click="date = ''">Clear</b-btn>
    </template>
  </b-input-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use v-model to accept the selected date and then clear it using JavaScript, it will be removed from date selection

Comment: Or you can add a button, which reset the v-model.

Comment: It's not poossible to type. Just can pick the date

Comment: Mostly I need to manually clear the date. However if I can manually  type the date would be wonderful because I can clear it too